# Unexpected requests.exceptions.ConnectionError

Tags: python, python-requests

I was trying to run this code:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get("https://upos-sz-mirrorkodo.bilivideoo1.com/")
```

But a BIG ERROR has raised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\王子涵\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026E92F17F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed     

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='upos-sz-mirrorkodo.bilivideoo1.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026E92F17F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Desktop\1.py", line 48, in <module>
    r = get(
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\VSC\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='upos-sz-mirrorkodo.bilivideoo1.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026E92F17F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

I tried to ping this host but failed, and Google didn't give useful advice.

Could you please tell me why and how to deal with it? Thanks a lot.

I have also asked this question on Github at https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6010.

Comment: *ping* is unable to resolve upos-sz-mirrorkodo.bilivideoo1.com

Comment: If you tried to ping this host and no results, it's the server's fault, not the `requests` library

Comment: Either this host doesn't exist, or it's on an unreachable private subnet.

Comment: Maybe you meant upos-sz-mirrorkodo.bilivideo.com

Comment: @JCaesar this host is pinging indeed but returns `959` http status code

Comment: @blazej ping has nothing to do with HTTP.

Comment: I think we have already established that the error is caused by whatever site OP was trying to access not his code. We can only speculate from this point onwards.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the URL you specified is simply **not reachable**. You said yourself that you cannot ping the host. Therefore, this issue is not related to your code. If you try `requests.get("https://www.google.com/")` it will probably work fine.

**Update:** Some comments pointed out that you might have a typo in your URL and that you meant to type:

```
upos-sz-mirrorkodo.bilivideo.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though it didn't hit my question!